# hide/show contact details based on subdomain entry point

Tags: jquery, wordpress, subdomain

We've put together a site for a property developer who has two selling contacts (builder and real estate agent) however the agreement between developer and sales consultants is that they have their 'own' subdomain entry point that only 'displays' their respective contact details to be fair. E.g. Real estate agent puts an ad on realestate . com and the prospect clicks through to the website from this listing (tony. wirelessstreetgardens. com.au - the other sales rep is kelly. wirelessstreetgardens. com.au - with the actual site displaying both www. wirelessstreetgardens. com.au if the lead comes about by organic means), the real estate agent only wants his contact details popping-up, not the builders sales rep details on the contact page and vice-versa if the enquiry came from the builders site (understandable).

I know it's possible using jQuery show/hide code however i'm getting stuck and was wondering if anyone had done this before successfully?

Obviously don't need the 'click' function in this:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
$("p").show();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you means to show and hide elements based on the URL, you can use an if statement that check if the URL contains that string (substitute 'subdomain' with yours)

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("subdomain") > -1) {
  $("p").show();
}
```